# Run Make on multiple folders

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the following structure to my makefile:

```
FOLDERS = folder
```

Currently, I am able to create a release and debug version in `folder/rel` and `folder/dbg`.
I would like to extend this so that I can change `FOLDERS` to

```
FOLDERS = folder1 folder2 folder3
```

And for every folder in the variable, it should compile all cpp files and move object files to `/rel` or `/dbg` (whichever is specified such as Makefile release or Makefile debug)

Additionally, the Makefile is one level above all the `FOLDERS`.

So, currently, I generate SOURCES using `$(wildcard $(FOLDERS)/*.cpp)`
which only works when FOLDERS contains one folder but not with two. --> example of it failing would be like `folder1 folder2/*.cpp` when the intention is `folder1/*.cpp` and `folder2/*.cpp`

Please let me know if more details are needed. I am new to this.

Comment: You can create a makefile folder.mk, that process a single folder ($FOLDER), and then invoke this makefile and passin the folder name $(MAKE) -f folder.mk FOLDER=folder1

Comment: i must do this all from one makefile

Answer (score 1):

You want `$(wildcard $(foo:=/*.cpp))`.